# SQL - Find subsets that meet combination of conditions

Tags: sql, subset

This example is a bit silly but it's basically what I'm dealing with... Let's say I've got 2 tables, T_PARENT and T_CHILDREN, where a parent can have 0..N children. A simplified example of the tables structure and data is as following:

- T_PARENT

| IDPARENT | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Carlos |

- T_CHILDREN

| IDPARENT | NAME | AGE | HEIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan | 9 | 120 |
| 1 | Juan | 9 | 110 |
| 1 | Pablo | 9 | 130 |
| 1 | Pablo | 9 | 120 |
| 1 | Pablo | 7 | 110 |
| 1 | Diego | 9 | 110 |
| 1 | Diego | 9 | 100 |

I need to find in the most efficient way which parents have children that meet the following conditions (this is an example of possible combinations):

1. At least 1 child where **name='Pablo'** (doesn't matter age or height).
2. At least 1 child where **name='Juan'** and **age=9** (doesn't matter height).
3. At least 1 child where **name='Diego'** and **age=9** and **height=110**
4. At least 1 child where **name='Diego'** and **age=9** and **height=120**

In this example with data, parent with IDPARENT=1 shouldn't be retrieved, because he doesn't have a child named Diego of age 9 and height 120.

**NOTE**: T_CHILDREN has an important restriction: values of NAME-AGE-HEIGHT columns must be unique- So for example, in this world as a parent, you can have N children named Pablo of age 9, but they cannot have same height.

So far, I can only think of accomplishing this doing 3 subqueries in worst case scenario:

```
SELECT p.IDPARENT
FROM T_PARENT p
WHERE 1 <= (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM T_CHILDREN c
    where c.IDPARENT = p.IDPARENT
    and c.NAME = 'Pablo'
)
AND 1 <= (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM T_CHILDREN c
    WHERE c.IDPARENT = p.IDPARENT
    AND c.NAME = 'Juan' AND c.AGE = 9
)
AND 2 <= (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM T_CHILDREN c
    WHERE c.IDPARENT = p.IDPARENT
    AND (c.NAME = 'Diego' AND c.AGE = 9 AND c.HEIGHT = 110)
    OR (c.NAME = 'Diego' AND c.AGE = 9 AND c.HEIGHT = 120)
);
```

Comment: The last subquery isn't bulletproof: if a parent has 2 Diego's with height 110 he/she will also be selected. You'll have to split it in two subqueries I guess.

Comment: Hi Johey, It would be fine; either way, that couldn't happen: You can't have 2 times a Diego-9-110, there is a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for those 3 columns. Last subquery could use a '2 =' instead of a '2 <=' operator.

Comment: Ok, you're right. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT T.IDPARENT, T.NAME
FROM T_PARENT T JOIN T_CHILDREN D
ON T.IDPARENT = D.IDPARENT
GROUP BY T.IDPARENT, T.NAME
HAVING
COUNT(CASE WHEN D.NAME='Pablo' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
COUNT(CASE WHEN D.NAME='Juan' AND D.AGE=9 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
COUNT(CASE WHEN D.NAME='Diego' AND D.AGE=9 AND D.HEIGHT=110 THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
COUNT(CASE WHEN D.NAME='Diego' AND D.AGE=9 AND D.HEIGHT=120 THEN 1 END) > 0
ORDER BY T.IDPARENT, T.NAME
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/we00gFLE).

Another option is to use `EXISTS` operator as the following:

```
SELECT T.IDPARENT, T.NAME
FROM T_PARENT T 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T_CHILDREN D WHERE T.IDPARENT = D.IDPARENT AND D.NAME='Pablo')
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T_CHILDREN D WHERE T.IDPARENT = D.IDPARENT AND  D.NAME='Juan' AND D.AGE=9)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T_CHILDREN D WHERE T.IDPARENT = D.IDPARENT AND D.NAME='Diego' AND D.AGE=9 AND D.HEIGHT=110)
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T_CHILDREN D WHERE T.IDPARENT = D.IDPARENT AND D.NAME='Diego' AND D.AGE=9 AND D.HEIGHT=120)
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TQLJ_03t).

Comment: Hi Ahmed, first thank you so much for your time and your help. I suposse the first solution would be better, right? Since you're avoiding 1 subquery per condition. I could have more conditions than just the mentioned above.

Comment: You are welcome, I think so. You may check the execution plan for both queries. [qr1](https://dbfiddle.uk/6FIPg1uP) --- [qr2](https://dbfiddle.uk/K9vqCCV9).